# How to lock an Electron app to landscape mode on Windows 8.1 tablets?

Tags: orientation, tablet, windows, electron

The title pretty much says it all. We have developed an HTML5 app that is designed to be held in landscape mode only (whether that is good or bad is besides the point).

When we use Cordova to build an appx for Windows 8.1, we can specify "landscape" as the only supported orientation. But we would prefer to build an exe file instead since it makes installing/updating/configuring the app much easier for our customer. It also gives us total control over which webview the app runs in.

However, it seems like there's no way of specifying supported orientations when building an Electron app?

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: I am having to do the same. Were you able to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: No, but to be honest I didn't look into the issue further.

Answer (score 2):

Electron APIs does not provide any way to force a landscape mode at this moment.

What you could do is to display a message when the user is in portrait mode using pure CSS, to tell him he has to turn the tablet in lanscape mode. Something like:

HTML

```
<div id="warning-portrait">Please turn your device in landscape mode</div>
<div id="wrap"><!-- your app --></div>
```

CSS

```
#warning-portrait { 
    display: none; 
}

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {

    #wrap { 
        display:none; 
    }

    #warning-portrait { 
        display:block; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) {

    #warning-portrait { 
        display:none; 
    }
}
```

Comment: As I suspected... yes, showing a message was something I was thinking about, that will have to do as a last resort. Thanks.

Comment: @Strille You might ask for this feature to the Electron dev team, but I'm not sure if Chromium supports it anyway